# FlexSlider: Always show snippet of the next slide

Tags: flexslider

Anybody know how I might set up FlexSlider to *always* reveal a portion of the *next* slide? For example:

[image: FlexSlider goal]

It would do this always, not when hovered over, etc. Essentially, it entices the viewer to continue looking through the panels. Naturally, I'd set `slideshow: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out; it's not *perfect*, but it's a great start:

```
.flex-active-slide + li {
    left: -1%;
    position: relative;
}
```

This says, "Hey, target the next `<li>` that is an adjacent sibling of `.flex-active-slide` (which is the currently active/visible slide), and move it left by a small amount."

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the flexslider function attribute 'itemMargin' to 0

Comment: Thanks Joe. I ended up figuring it out a while back (see the other answer for this question). You can see it in action here: https://advertising.paypal.com/